# How to make own invoice template in odoo13, module

Tags: xml, templates, odoo, invoice, odoo-13

I made my own template for invoices and at the moment my template overwrites the original report_invoice_document template, but I don t want my template to delete the original. I guess I I have a mistake in ids. Can anyone advise how to do that. Here my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <report
                id="account_invoices"
                model="account.invoice"
                string="Invoices"
                report_type="qweb-pdf"
                name="report_invoice_template.report_invoice"
                file="report_invoice_template.report_invoice"
        />
        <template id="account.report_invoice_document">
            <t t-name="account.report_invoice_document">
                <t t-call="web.external_layout">
                    <t t-set="o" t-value="o.with_context(lang=lang)"/>
```

Comment: You used the original report id as template id. `account.report_invoice_document` is the external id of the invoice report document template.

Comment: thanks, do I have to change the templateid to my own is that enough?

Comment: Yes, why `<t t-name="account.report_invoice_document">`?

Comment: when I change the name or template id it says no template that can be upgraded. I just followed the documentation...

Comment: You can add your template as they did for [report invoice](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/account/views/report_invoice.xml#L219)